# What does this error message mean? Messages in iCloud not available as iCloud and iMessage accounts do not match

Tags: iphone, icloud

I am trying to troubleshoot why, suddenly, my iPhone is not able to share photos. This just  started happening today. No problem previously. One of the troubleshooting steps advised logging out of iCloud, which I was trying to do when I got the error message below, which I don't understand even on the basic grammatical level:

> Messages in iCloud not available as iCloud and iMessage accounts do not match
>
> Messages in iCloud is [sic] not available because iCloud and iMessage accounts are different

What is Apple trying to say here?

Comment: 'Messages in iCloud' is possibly how Apple refers to the name of the service, hence why it's referred to in the singular. Your messages in (the) iCloud *are* plural. Hope that explains the grammar.

Comment: That makes sense.  The whole sequence of events was confusing.  I had logged out of iCloud and was expecting some message to the effect that I had successfully logged out.  All things iCloud should be unavailable.